# Errors when using a FragmentTabHost inside a Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tabhost

Im' trying to add a `FragmentTabHost` inside a `Fragment`(which is the content of another tab widget.

I used the following xml:

```
<android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <FrameLayout
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0"/>
        <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/realtabcontent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost>
```

And in my `Fragment`'s `onCreateView()` method:

```
View basicSearchView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.search_layout, container, false);
        try {
        mTabHost = (FragmentTabHost) basicSearchView.findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
        LocalActivityManager mLocalActivityManager = new LocalActivityManager(this, false);
        mTabHost.setup(mLocalActivityManager);

        TabHost.TabSpec tab = mTabHost.newTabSpec("my tab content");

        tab.setContent(new Intent(getActivity(), JoinActivity.class));
        tab.setIndicator("Test", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.search_pheeds_selector));
        mTabHost.addTab(tab);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Udi",e.getMessage());
        }

        return basicSearchView;
```

At first Igot the following error:

```
ERROR/Udi(25726): Must call setup() that takes a Context and FragmentManager
```

Afterwards I've changed the setup to:

```
mTabHost.setup(getActivity(), getChildFragmentManager(), R.id.realtabcontent);
```

And I got this error instead:

```
ERROR/Udi(25996): Did you forget to call 'public void setup(LocalActivityManager activityGroup)'?
```

Is there a proper way to put tab host inside a `Fragment`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't read the documentation for the [`FragmentTabHost`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentTabHost.html) class which clearly states that `FragmentTabHost` is a *Special TabHost that allows the use of Fragment objects for its tab content.*. So you can't setup the tabs to be activities and it would not make sense anyway as you're trying to have activities in fragments(it should be the other way around).

So modify your code to use fragments as the tabs content or use a normal `TabHost` in an `Activity` to continue using those activities as tabs(this option is deprecated and you should really go with the first option).

> Is there a proper way to put tab host inside a Fragment?

In the documentation I've linked you have an example, if I'm not mistaken there are some examples in the support library's samples.