# Unable to get Fragment tab controller working

Tags: android

I have the following setup in my Android project with a tab-based view

ToDoActivity.class:

```
private FragmentTabHost mTabHost;
private User user;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_todos);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
    String username = bundle.getString("username");
    this.user = new User(TodoActivity.this, username);

    mTabHost = (FragmentTabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
    mTabHost.setup(this, getSupportFragmentManager(), R.id.realtabcontent);

    // Tab for 'active' tasks
    TabSpec tasksTab = mTabHost.newTabSpec("Tasks");
    // setting Title and Icon for the Tab
    tasksTab.setIndicator("Tasks", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_tasks_tab));
    Intent activeIntent = new Intent(this, ActiveTasks.class);
    tasksTab.setContent(activeIntent);

     // Tab for completed tasks
     TabSpec compeltedTasks = mTabHost.newTabSpec("Completed");        
     compeltedTasks.setIndicator("Completed", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_completed_tab));
     Intent completedIntent = new Intent(this, CompletedTasks.class);
     compeltedTasks.setContent(completedIntent);

     // Adding all TabSpec to TabHost
     mTabHost.addTab(tasksTab); 
     mTabHost.addTab(compeltedTasks);
}
```

activity_todos:xml

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"

        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/realtabcontent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

</LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost>
```

everytime I run it and attempt to transition to the tab view, I'm getting the following error:

```
02-24 10:03:38.705: E/AndroidRuntime(3791): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start      activity ComponentInfo{edu.gatech.team6.todo/edu.gatech.team6.todo.TodoActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Did you forget to call 'public void setup(LocalActivityManager activityGroup)'?
```

But I did call setup?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't read the documentation for the FragmentTabHost class which clearly states that FragmentTabHost is a Special TabHost that allows the use of Fragment objects for its tab content.. So you can't setup the tabs to be activities and it would not make sense anyway as you're trying to have activities in fragments(it should be the other way around).

So modify your code to use fragments as the tabs content or use a normal TabHost in an Activity to continue using those activities as tabs(this option is deprecated and you should really go with the first option).

Answer fount at : [Errors when using a FragmentTabHost inside a Fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15338320/errors-when-using-a-fragmenttabhost-inside-a-fragment)

Comment: I have read the documentation, the activities (ActiveTasks and CompletedTasks) are both Fragment objects. Isn't that the way the FragmentTabHost was intended to work?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was adding the Intent:

```
 Intent activeIntent = new Intent(this, ActiveTasks.class);
 tasksTab.setContent(activeIntent);
```

Once I took those away and added the Class as the second parameter to addTab(), it worked fine.